# resource '$this.icon' could not be instantiated in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to open an old project , but when I open(Form1.cs) it give me an error on particular forms designer view that

> The parameter is incorrect

Heres the call stack

```
at System.Drawing.Icon.Initialize(Int32 width, Int32 height)
at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(Stream stream, Int32 width, Int32 height)
at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(Stream stream)
at System.Drawing.IconConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(Object value)
at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GenerateObjectFromDataNodeInfo(DataNodeInfo dataNodeInfo, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GetValue(ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseDataNode(XmlTextReader reader, Boolean isMetaData)
at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseXml(XmlTextReader reader)
```

When I try to open Form1.resx file it gave me an error:

> resource '$this.icon' could not be instantiated

I researched at it says it because it might be on .NET 2.0, but mine is in .NET 3.5 and its on VS2008.

So , can any one tell me hwo to fix this issue, as its old one and we cannot recreate it.

Thanks

Comment: Done some research on it. And it says it could be because format of ICON file I am using is not compatible with XP, as initially it was made on WIN8. Now, my question is how to change the format of that ICON file.

Comment: Create a new icon for the project in the IDE in a format XP will accept (ie, 16x16x4 bit). Once created, save your work. Now manually edit Form1.cs in notepad. Replace the $this.Icon with a manual load icon command or try to set the icon through the properties pane for Form1.